# How to pre-load images on vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I want to load all the images on-page to be preload(when routing changes).
all the images I used are stored locally. when I test the network images are loading when scrolling. I need to be load images on page mount not on scroll.

```html
 <div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 10vh;">
  <v-layout row wrap justify-center>
    <v-flex
      md12
      align-self-center
      data-aos-easing="linear"
      data-aos-delay="100"
      data-aos="fade-up"
      data-aos-duration="1500"
    >
      <v-img
        contain
        height="90vh"
        src="../assets/chamika_house/_SDS3575.jpg"
      ></v-img>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</div>
<div style="width:99vw;height:36vh;padding:10px"></div>

<div>
  <v-img
    contain
    height="95vh"
    src="../assets/chamika_house/_SDS3429.jpg"
    data-aos="fade-up"
    data-aos-easing="linear"
    data-aos-delay="100"
    data-aos-duration="1500"
  ></v-img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<v-img>` has an [`eager` prop](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-img/#props) that disables lazy loading:

```html
<v-img eager />
```

Comment: Yes, loading on scroll is called "lazy loading".